# Write a macro for C/C++ #include

Tags: c, macros, include, ibm-midrange

I work on AS/400 which is sometimes non-POSIX.  We also need to compile our code on UNIX.  We have an issue with something as simple as #include.

On AS/400, we need to write:

```
#include "*LIBL/H/MYLIB"
```

On UNIX, we need to write

```
#include "MYLIB.H"
```

At the moment we have this (ugly) block at the top of each C/C++ file:

```
#ifndef IS_AS400
    #include "*LIBL/H/MYLIB"
    /* others here */
#else
    #include "MYLIB.H"
    /* others here */
#endif
```

We would like a unified macro.  Is this possible?  I don't know how to write it.

Ideally, the resulting syntax would be:

```
SAFE_INCLUDE("MYLIB")
```

that would expand correctly on each platform.

Please advise.

Comment: The form I've used for at least the last ten years is `#include <except.h>`.

Comment: That's kind of an interesting requirement. Does AS400 *not* allow a dot in filenames?

Comment: @jww: AS400 has fundamentally different file system than  Unix/Linux/BSD/Windows.  First, the content is not "free form"; second, the hierarchy is severly limited.  See also: VMS file system.

Comment: OK, thanks. I occasionally worked with an AS400 years ago, but it provided SAMBA, so I did not suffer those limitations. The trouble I had was I could not get filesystem change notifications because it was not a native Windows machine or a Windows filesystem. I think I was using [FindFirstChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply `#include` some separate header in every of your source files containing that ugly `#ifndef` just once. It's a common practice anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You can define prefixes for your platform as macro. Like

```
#define STRINGY(STR) #STR
#define SAFE_INCLUDE(HDR) STRINGY(HDR)

#ifndef IS_AS400
#define SAFE_INCLUDE(LIB) STRINGY(*LIBL/H/##LIB)
#else
#define SAFE_INCLUDE(LIB) STRINGY(LIB##.H)
#endif
```

and you can use this as

```
#include SAFE_INCLUDE(MYLIB)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's more versatile than my advise in the case where there are more than one such header. Should be accepted if it's the case.

Answer (score 4):

There are two better solutions:

1. Use your Makefiles to properly set a path where compiler looks for includes.
   For GCC you add to CFLAGS `-I <path>` (you can do that multiple times).
2. Wrap the non-compliant libraries with your own header files.

Comment: The problem is when header files are not "header.h" but "h/header" or "h(header)". All file systems are not created equal!