# Abstracting include paths and library names with pkg-config?

Tags: autotools, crypto++, pkg-config

I'm working with a project that goes by one of two *package* names, depending on the distribution. On Debian and derivatives, the package name is ***`libcrypto++`***. On Fedora and derivates, its called ***`libcryptopp`***. (The official project name is Crypto++).

Users write code, and do things like:

```
#include <crypto++/aes.h>
```

And later, they link to the library with `-lcrypto++`.

Obviously, using "Debian conventions" breaks things on Fedora (and vice versa). See, for example, [How to change the include file path with autotools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32805772)

I'm trying to determine what can be used to abstract the differences away so the user's code "just works".

Can [`pkg-config files`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config) be used to handle the differences? If so, then how does it handle the `#include <crypto++/...>` versus `#include <cryptopp/...>` found in user code? (I'm especially concerned about header clashes, like OpenSSL and Crypto++ both providing `aes.h`).

If not, what can we do to help with the issues caused by different names on different platforms?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built-in to the auto-tools that would do this automatically.  It's a fairly unusual need.

There are ways you could get this to work.  Here are a couple:

- Make a symlink in your build tree, with the name you like, pointing to the include tree.  That is, symlink from `libcrypto++` to `/usr/include/libcrytpopp`; then use `#include <libcrypto++/mumble>` in your source.  You can make this symlink from `configure`.
- Generate a new C macro definition at `configure` time (see `AC_DEFINE`) that expands to a string holding the prefix, e.g., `"libcryptopp"`.  Then use pasting in the `#include` line to include the proper header.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6813253/1442050).

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Tromey said there is nothing to help you much with this by itself. But with the help of the Crypto++ developers you could come up with a more standardized approach to discover this.

The trick is using `pkg-config` defined variables, and then use Tom's suggested approach of a macro and pasting. Essentially you just need to define the prefix variable in your `.pc` file:

```
includepathprefix = libcryptopp
```

And then use `PKG_CHECK_VAR` to read it through.

```
PKG_CHECK_VAR([CRYPTOPP_PREFIX], [libcrypto++], [includepathprefix])
AC_DEFINE([CRYPTOPP_PREFIX], [$CRYPTOPP_PREFIX],
    [Prefix for crypto++ header files.])
```

then you should use string pasting to include the files. It's definitely clunky, but it is slightly less of a shot in the dark.

I wrote more information about `PKG_CHECK_VAR` on my [Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/variables.html) if you want to see the full syntax.